# Ruby on Rails: How to validate form that is split into tabs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm improving RoR application. In this app there is a page where user can crete or edit items. This page contains form. In that form there are 11 tabs (implemented with javascript, we use bootsrap's tabbable here). Form controls are divided between 11 tabs.

There is a problem: After user submits form with wrong data in 2nd or 3rd tab, the same form is shown, and first tab is activated.

I need to solve this problem. I want not to use client side validation. All validation should be done in rails. Also I don't want to use AJAX.

So if user submits form that have wrong data in 5th tab, then 5th tab must be shown after submit, and form error messages should be placed into 5th tab. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is a Javascript one - **`how to load up validation errors in the correct tabs?`**

From my perspective, it seems Rails is handling the data you send, and returns the original page your request was sent from. The problem is this does not load the correct tabs, which is JS' responsibility (front-end)

---

**Recommendation**

I would personally create an anonymous function to load up the tabs which have errors. You need to remember tabs are all HTML elements, and Rails append `field_with_error` wrapper around fields with errors

I don't have any experience with [Bootstrap tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), but you could do something like this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(function() {
    $('#myTab .div_with_errors:first').tab('show')
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

The problem is that it's pretty difficult to find tab with errors. Error messages are shown above tabs.

Maybe it's possible to serialize model with error messages to json and pass it to javascript using Gon gem. In javascript I can map error message to certain tab and highlight this tab. But this approach looks like dirty workaround. I try to avoid spreading logic between ruby and javascript. I try to keep logic in one place.

Comment: My question is not only about code. It is also about finding better UI approach :)

I thought about my question for a while and came up with 2 solutions:
1) Activate the same tab after page submit. If user was on #administrators tab before submit, then I pass "administrators" in hidden input, and highlight same tab after submit. This way is not very comfortable for users, but it is much more better than directing users to first tab after each form submit.
2) Make rich JavaScript application with lots of javascript code and instant validation (before form submit).

Comment: I followed approach #1, it was very fast to implement it.

BTW many popular websites render each tab on separate page, without using JavaScript tabs. I wanted to create separate page for every tab, but client insisted on using javascript tabs. This requirement adds complexity to the project, but I cannot skip this requirement.